# Unresolved external symbol errors for functions defined in tdh.h

Tags: c, windows, linker, linker-errors

I am getting the following linker errors when I compile my C Windows program:

```
(Link target) ->
  libossec.lib(read_win_trace_log.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TdhFormatProperty [C:\path\to\project.vcxproj]
  libossec.lib(read_win_trace_log.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TdhGetPropertySize [C:\path\to\project.vcxproj]
  libossec.lib(read_win_trace_log.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TdhGetEventInformation [C:\path\to\project.vcxproj]
  libossec.lib(read_win_trace_log.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TdhGetEventMapInformation [C:\path\to\project.vcxproj]
  libossec.lib(read_win_trace_log.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TdhGetProperty [C:\path\to\project.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\Administrator\src\lich\lichsrc\x64\Release\lich.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals [C:\path\to\project.vcxproj]
```

If necessary I can include my source code, but it is very large (the file is over 600 lines long).

I include `tdh.h` in my `read_win_trace_log.c`. I checked, and there are function prototypes for each of these functions in the `tdh.h` system header. So these linker errors shouldn't be because of any implicit function prototypes.

I looked at the `tdh.h` source code, and it already wraps everything in `extern "C"`, so the code should be callable from my C code.

I compile using the Visual Studio compiler, but from the command line using a manually maintained `.vcxproj` file.

Is it possible I am missing a `.lib` or `.dll` that I need to link to build successfully?

Comment: Where are those `TdhFormatProperty` symbols defined? In some .oib file or in some .c/.cpp source files? Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: These functions have their prototypes in the `tdh.h` system header, which I include. I am not sure where the function bodies are. I am using Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

As documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tdh/nf-tdh-tdhformatproperty), in order to use the the functions in the `tdh.h` header, you need to link against the `tdh.lib` library.

Use the **Project>Properties** command and add `tdh.lib` as shown below:

[image]